# Temporarily disable hover when a button is clicked (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, click

I have a small "interactive slideshow" on my About page, in which the user can click 1 of 5 buttons, and see the resulting "slide". Each "slide" is a `<section>` element, with varying content inside. When the page loads, the first button ("About Me"), should be red. Here are the other requirements:

- When user clicks on any button, it should change to red  **AND  all others** should change to blue.

  - This same button **must** stay red when the user "leaves" the button
- When user hovers over any button, it should change to red, and then back to blue when the user leaves it

  - Unless this button is the current button, in which case it must remain red
- There **must always** be 1 button that is red, as this indicates the previous slide.
- **Only 2** buttons may be red at a time (one from a previous click, and one from current hover).

[image: Example]

I have the `.click()` event working perfectly, but I cannot seem to get the `.hover()` effect to work simultaneously. When I have the two effects running, the `hover` effect overrides the `click` effect. As soon as my mouse leaves the button *after clicking it*, the background changes to `dodgerblue`, even though it should remain `indianred` (I think this is because of the 'mouseoff' part of the hover event).

I have looked at similar questions, but cannot find one that answers my current questions.

Any suggestions?

```
var aryButtons = $('.button');
$(aryButtons[0]).css('background-color', 'indianred');

// IMPORTANT - If you comment this section out, the hover effect disappears, but the click function works. However, I need to have both working at once, so that when a button is clicked, it will stay indian red even when the user leaves the element. In addition, they need to be able to hover over other elements again.

$(aryButtons).hover(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'indianred');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'dodgerblue');
});

$(aryButtons).click(function () {
    $.each(aryButtons, function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'dodgerblue');
    });

    $(this).css('background-color', 'indianred');
});
```

```html
<section class="button"></section>
<section class="button"></section>
<section class="button"></section>
```

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/UnaviaMedia/b3ozk00p/8/

Comment: FYI you should always include the relevant code in your question in case the external website goes down.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thanks for the information. I'll remember that in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3ozk00p/4/)

You're using the wrong tool.

CSS is much better suited to this task.  All the jQuery needs to do is flip the class.

**Add this CSS**

```
.button.clicked {
    background-color: indianred;
}
.button.clicked:hover {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: indianred;
}
```

**Change Javascript to this**

```
aryButtons.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Note: You don't need to re-wrap everything in `$(...)` whenever you want to use jQuery with it.  Your declaration of `$('.buttons')` for `aryButtons` will persist as a jQuery object.  That's why we got rid of that.  You should be using the `.on` function for event binding as it allows you to toggle events being tracked on an element.  Anything that ends up in an event binding call to jQuery needs to be a `function`, so we wrapped the `$(this).toggleClass()` call in an anonymous function.  That should solve all the issues with your code.

## Update:

So, after additional requirements, here's the updated fiddle:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3ozk00p/12/)**

Again, fairly straightforward:

**JavaScript**

```
aryButtons.on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});
```

**All additional CSS**

```
.button.clicked,
.button.clicked.waiting:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: indianred;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I only want the clicked element to change to `indianred`. The rest should remain (or change to) `dodgerblue`.

Comment: Your use of `$.each` in the `.click()` function was the culprit for that behavior.

Comment: Hmm. Now when I click the sections (in your fiddle), they still don't remain red. That's what I was running into with mine.

Comment: Check the further update.  I took it the rest of the way.  You were close, but it's obvious you're starting out with jQuery.  It's a powerful tool, and once you get the swing of it things like this will be super easy.  I wish you the best of luck in continuing to learn.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for how unclear I have been. Your fiddle is closer than what I had, but still not quite what I need (which is my fault). I will completely re-edit this question, and include a picture of the site. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks so much for your time and willingness to revamp to meet my changes!

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you, i created a self invoking function and inside i created a variable called clicked_btn that holds the value of the current button that was clicked, this variable is accessible from within the click and hover methods, so whatever button is clicked it's color is changed to indianred and stays indianred, and when hovered over it changes color as well except the one that was clicked.

```
(function(){
  var clicked_btn = "";
  $('.button').click(function(){
  clicked_btn = $(this); 
  (clicked_btn).css('background-color','indianred');
  $('.button').not(this).css('background-color','dodgerblue');
});

$('.button').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','indianred');        
},function(){
  $('.button').not(clicked_btn).css('background-color','dodgerblue');
});

})();
```

Example in jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ypcpyr2q/

Answer (score 0):

Just made something like that work....  do the selectors   :active:hover and put the original style back to the non hover state. It overrides the active or hover alone

ie:

:active {blah blah}

:hover {blah blah}

:active:hover {this is the one that will work if clicked (and obviously hovered) at the same time

Comment: i think i must have misread the original post...so I re-read it. Here is a JS fiddle for you to look at that does what you want....

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/carinlynchin/oedd0s4u/4/)